# Развернуть sentry

Tags: devops

Хочу развернуть свой sentry. [Глянул](https://github.com/getsentry/onpremise/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) и ужаснулся. Почему так много разных сервисов? Можно ли обойтись чем-то меньшим?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Почему так много разных сервисов?

Новая реализация на stream`ах. Cделали видимо для highload проектов.

> Можно ли обойтись чем-то меньшим?

Да, потесть эту [версию](https://github.com/AfsmNGhr/devops-swarm-mode/blob/master/services/sentry/docker-compose.swarm.yml). Можно взять версии по-свежее. Правда, помню, в какой-то версии `smtp` работал не стабильно.